# Perl AUTOLOAD - get name of unknown method without class name

Tags: perl, class, namespaces, autoload

I am writing an `AUTOLOAD` subroutine for a Perl class. I can get the name of the unknown method with `$name = $ExampleClass::AUTOLOAD;`. However this gets me the full identifier: `ExampleClass::unknownmethodname`. I just need `unknownmethodname`. How can I only get that portion of the name? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
( my $method_name = our $AUTOLOAD ) =~ s/^.*:://s;
```

or

```
my $method_name = our $AUTOLOAD =~ s/^.*:://sr;    # 5.14+
```

Comment: thank you that worked! Can you explain what it does?

Comment: If `$AUTOLOAD` contains `Foo::Bar::baz`, it returns `baz`.

Comment: The invocant and the other arguments you need are in `@_`. (I don't know why you'd need the calling "class", but the calling package is available via `caller`.)

Answer (score 1):

To retain the calling class name as well as the method name, write

```perl
my ($class, $method) = $AUTOLOAD =~ /(.+)::(.+)/;
```

This splits the string in `$AUTOLOAD` into two parts: the part up to the last occurrence of `::` and the part afterwards.

Using your own example

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

our $AUTOLOAD = 'ExampleClass::unknownmethodname';

my ($class, $method) = $AUTOLOAD =~ /(.+)::(.+)/;

say "\$class  = $class";
say "\$method = $method";
```

#### output

```
$class  = ExampleClass
$method = unknownmethodname
```

---

#### Update

I can't imagine why you would want to split on the *first* occurrence of `::`, as it would result in an arbitrary chunk of the class name for the first part, followed by the rest of the class name and the method name for the second part

But you could just use `split` with a limit

```
my ($part1, $part2) = split /::/, $AUTOLOAD, 2;
```

or using a similar regex to the above

```
my ($part1, $part2) = $AUTOLOAD =~ /([^:]+)::(.+)/;
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147194/discussion-between-borodin-and-achang27).